# mqtt publish/subscribe key exchange?

Tags: mqtt, cryptography

I'm realy a newbie in cryptography, I want to do MQTT payload encryption with AES, i've done it with PyCrypto library, but i'm still wondering how I can encrypt AES key before sending it to the subscriber, so i choose Python library called PyNacl to do that with ECC (curve25519), but i have no idea how to exchange the public key between the publisher and subscriber, have you any idea to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public keys by definition are public (no need to keep them secret).

So there is no reason it can't be available for download via http or at a push published as a retained message on a known MQTT topic.

Comment: thanks for responding
if i got what you said , i can exchange public key in a separate topic  and play with the code so that the message is sent only after receipt of the public key , right?

Comment: As a retained message the key would be delivered to the device as soon as it subscribed to the topic

Comment: please I am stuck in python code, here is the scenario, client A want to send encrypted data to client B, but first he must receive client B public key, so both client A and B are publisher and subscriber at the same time on the same topic, client B send his public key as a retained message then B encrypt data and send it to B, for me it seems confusing when i want to implement it in paho mqtt python , have you any example to do that ?